# Buttons linked with PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Im not sure how to introduce this, i have a problem...
Okay well here is the code:

```
<button class="a2 menu-button-start" onclick="<?php echo "window.location.href = \"index.php?p=129&l=$lang\";"; ?>" id="a2a">Home</button>
```

Here is my problem:
Its not taking me to the link.

I have not much to say other than the `p` variable defines the page, and the `l` variable defines the language.
I dont think you need to know anything else.

Comment: why do this with javascript, when you could just use a regular html link (and style it to look like a button if you want).

Comment: you have `";` twice, and why have it like that if p is always the same? why dont you have only `echo $lang`?

Comment: `I dont think you need to know anything else`, how about what the actually problem is? What's happening? Any errors you get from debugging? What the variables actually echo out into the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button class="a2 menu-button-start" onclick="<?php echo "window.location.href = 'index.php?p=129&l=" . $lang . "';"; ?>" id="a2a">Home</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But can you tell me what i did wrong?

Comment: `"` inside `onclick` closes `onclick`, so you have to use `'` inside `onclick` instead of `"`.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this since you are only dynamically getting $lang:

```
<button class="a2 menu-button-start" onclick="window.location.href='index.php?p=129&l=<?php echo $lang ?>';" id="a2a">Home</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Home" onclick="goToPage();" id="a2a">

<script>
function goToPage() {
<?php echo "window.location.href = 'index.php?p=129&l=' . $lang; . '";"' ?>
}
</script>
```

Comment: The php would be cleaner like `{ window.location.href = 'index.php?p=129&l=<?= $lang ?>'; }`

Comment: I guess...  I was going from the point of view that he needed to generate the string using both anyway...  May as well do it all in one shot.  But it's really the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

should be

```
     onclick="window.location.href=<?php echo 'index.php?p=129&l='.$lang;?>;"
```